# Multiplying numbers with different bases with the same exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Solving a problem about simplification ("simplify $(2^n-2^{n-1})(3^n-3^{n-1})")$, I got this:
$$ 2^n\cdot 3^n $$

I don't recall learning about multiplying numbers with different bases and same exponents, but doing some tests I guessed the answer was $6^n$, and it turned out to be correct.

Is this property always applicable? How can this property be proved in a generalized way?

Comment: The two answers below provide a good explanation so I'll just leave this here as a comment. Remember that this only works where multiplication is commutative. This is true pretty much wherever you're working with numbers, so you don't need to worry about it here. But this might not be true in non-abelian groups. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it comes from the commutative and associative properties of multiplication.  Let's say we had $2^3\cdot 3^3$.  This gives $(2\cdot 2 \cdot 2)\cdot(3\cdot 3\cdot 3)$.  Using associativity and commutativity, we can rewrite this as $(2\cdot 3)\cdot (2\cdot 3)\cdot (2\cdot 3)$ or, $6\cdot 6\cdot 6$ or $6^3$.  As you can see, since the exponents are the same, we can match each base with the other base.  It does not depend on the value of $n$.  Therefore, $A^n\cdot B^n = (AB)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, basic way, we can interpret $a^n$ as the product of $a$ with itself $n$ times, so:

$(ab)^n=ab\cdots ab=a\cdots a b \cdots b=a^nb^n$.